# Как сделать так чтоб если у человека в адресной строке указан неверный путь, то сайт автоматически перебрасывал его на стартовую страницу на ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router-dom

Как сделать так чтоб если у человека в адресной строке указан неверный путь, то сайт автоматически перебрасывал его на стартовую страницу на ReactJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать например так: Добавляем `Switch` то есть только один `Route` будет выбран. Если не один не подходит то срабатывает `Redirect`. В данном случае имеем только 2 достуаных пути: корень `/` и `/validpath`

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Redirect, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Link to="/validpath">Go to valid path</Link>
      </div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => "Root"} />
        <Route path="/validpath" render={() => "Valid Path"} />
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```